# External assemblies not working at design time

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2015, design-time

I'm having a trouble I can't find a solution for (everything I've found so far is not really relevant to my problem). For some reason, my Visual Studio (I use the 2015 Community Edition with Resharper Ultimate 2015.1.3) shows me errors and warnings at design time whenever I try to use anything that comes from an external assembly, which prevents me from seeing the window. This includes styles and classes (such as the MetroWindow from MahApps). Everything works when I compile and run it.
An example I can provide is the openly available demo code from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/442856/Visual-Studio-Metro-Styles-for-WPF, but really, just anything that uses external classes is fine.

The warning I get is: "Assembly 'MahApps.Metro' is not referenced by this project" - and it clearly is referenced.

The error: "The name "MetroWindow" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"."

[image: Should look a bit more clear on the screenshot.]

The example of the "faulty" code is the window definition itself, taken directly from the sample.
`<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Selen.Wpf.DemoApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" Title="Enterprise Commander"
        Height="800" Width="1000" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" TitleForeground="#999988"
         ShowMaxRestoreButton="False">
...
</Controls:MetroWindow>`

EDIT: I found a workaround - deleting MahApps and readding it with NuGet helped. Though having to do that doesn't feel right.

Comment: Can you post your xaml?  And let us know if/where your are getting errors underlined in the code?

Comment: Happens to me too.  I think it's something wrong in the designer.  It's really annoying.  Everything compiles and runs fine though.

Comment: @mrsargent The highlighted part is in the post now.

Comment: Is your application 32 or 64-bit?

Comment: Can you edit your post and add there?

Comment: @BrianWarshaw The application should be 32 bit. I tried the trick with changing the platform from "Any CPU" to "x86", but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to delete MahApps and add it again with NuGet - I guess that's how I should add external stuff in future.

Answer (score 0):

atleast for the MahApps you might you should try

```
xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
```

instead of

```
xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
```

Comment: Tried that, same error (The name "MetroWindow" does not exist in the namespace "http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls".)

Comment: @Noctiphobia MetroWindow is also not in this namespace. MetroWindow is defined in themes. /MahApps.Metro;component/Themes/MetroWindow.xaml